# Conditionally remove substrings in text with PHP

Tags: php, regex, substring

My scenario is I have a string containing raw html, for example:

```
Remove this tag: <img src="path/to/image">. 
Also remove this tag: <img src="path/to/second/image">. 
But don't touch this <img src="cid:1259asdhasi">.
```

What I need to do is find all img-tags within my string, check if their `src` begins with `cid:`, and if not, remove the entire tag.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead based regex in `preg_replace`

```
preg_replace('~<img\b[^>]*\ssrc="(?!cid:)[^>]*>~', '', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rE9iJ0/3)

Comment: or `preg_replace('~<img\b[^>]*\ssrc=['"](?!cid:)[^>]*>~', '', $str);`